# What representations should I choose to configure ExoPlayer

Tags: android, mpeg-dash, exoplayer

I'm trying to use ExoPlayer to play a DASH video with several qualities.

As far as I know DASH allows me to define several periods, and several qualities for each period, so it can switch qualities according to network speed, when next period is started.

The tutorial on http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/exoplayer.html suggest that I get the `audioRepresentations` and the `videoRepresentations` and pass them along. They can be parsed from a MPD file using `MediaPresentationDescriptionParser` class.

My question is: in the case of N periods and 2 qualities... should I pass only two representations (taken from the first period, as a sample), or should I pass a list of all representations from all periods?